# Switch statement not returning correct value

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, adapter

I am using switch statement in recycler view adapter's `getItemViewType` . None of the case in Switch statement in `getItemViewType` get called. I print log and it says the code didn't falls any switch statement. I am not getting where this code has mistake. Any help would appreciate. Thanks

```
  @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        Log.d(TAG, "getItemViewType: Type "+wrapper.getMESSAGE_TYPE()); // it return class 12
        if (Session.getUserID().equals(wrapper.getOTHER_USER_ID())){

            switch (wrapper.getMESSAGE_TYPE()){
                case "class 0":                    
                    return 0;

                case "class 1":
                    return 1;

                case "class 2":
                    return 2;

                case "class 3":
                    return 3;

                case "class 4":
                    return 4;

                case "class 5":
                    return 5;

                case "class 6":
                    return 6;

                case "class 7":
                    return 7;

                case "class 8":
                    return 8;

                case "class 9":
                    return 9;

                case "class 10":
                    return 10;

                case "class 11":
                    return 11;

                case "class 12":
                    Log.d(TAG, "getItemViewType: 12  "+wrapper.getMESSAGE_TYPE()); // it's not calling 
                    return 12;
            }
        }else {

            switch (wrapper.getMESSAGE_TYPE()){
                case "class 0":
                   return 0;
                case "class 1":
                    return 1

                case "class 2":
                    return 2

                case "class 3":
                    return 3

                case "class 4":
                    return 4

                case "class 5":
                    return 5

                case "class 6":
                    return 6

                case "class 7":
                    return 7

                case "class 8":
                    return 8

                case "class 9":
                    return 9

                case "class 10":
                    return 10

                case "class 11":
                    return 11

                case "class 12":             
                Log.d(TAG, "getItemViewType: 12  "+wrapper.getMESSAGE_TYPE()); // it's not calling  either       
                    return 12


            }
        }

         // none of above case called and code then falls into this below code

        Log.d(TAG,"End Of Get Item View Type = "+wrapper.getMESSAGE_TYPE()); // its return class 12
        boolean checkValue;
        if (wrapper.getMESSAGE_TYPE().equals("class 12")){
            Log.d(TAG, "getItemViewType:Check  "+wrapper.getMESSAGE_TYPE());
            checkValue = true;
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "getItemViewType:Check 2nd  "+wrapper.getMESSAGE_TYPE());
            checkValue = false;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "getItemViewType: Check Value ==== "+checkValue); // check value here is true
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
```

Comment: maybe adding a `default` case to each `switch` and printing/logging the actual message type (or so) can show what is going on (also check for non-printing characters)

Comment: @user85421 As i posted in question too what i am printing and which case should call after getting correct case even at start of getitemviewtype method. I will try to add default it might work. If there is any code you need to see please let me know. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: suggestion (for debugging); do something like `String type = wrapper.getMESSAGE_TYPE()` so the method is called only once (use `type` variable everywhere, including logging)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `String` `switch-case statements` are available from the JAVA version of 1.7. If you are using below than that, none of cases will get the trigger. To achieve this please use the `Enum` method and when we use that we can be done this work in a perfect manner.

Comment: if you know android studio comes with JAVA version 6/5 by default so i know this thing but to be more clear i am using java 8